# regex awk match between pattern, skipping first occurrence of endpat

Tags: regex, awk

I have a problem. I want to match lines between two patterns, inclusive. I can do that. Let's say this is what I've got:

```
art
subject

Course Material
paint
brush
easel
beret

art

Skills learned
oil
pastel
ink
chalk


math
subject

Course Material
book
calculator
etc...
```

I'll use the standard  `awk '/^art/ , /subject/' file`  and get

```
art 
subject

art

Skills learned
oil
pastel
ink
chalk


math
subject
```

This is the best I can do. The problem is that it cuts the art description into two parts.  The question I have is:

- How do I use the first art match, skip the first discipline match and then use the second discipline match?

Comment: So you want the 'Course Material' paragraph (for 'art') included in the output?  And the inclusion of 'math' and 'subject' is acceptable?

Comment: Yes. If you used the regex as markers it would look like this ART---[ignore 1st subject]----[ignore 2nd ART]-----SUBJECT

Comment: Everything inbetween the first ART and the second SUBJECT. Inclusion of math and subject are acceptable as I cannot figure out to do the first part anyways.

Comment: wrt `I'll use the standard awk '/^art/ , /subject/' file` - a range expression like that is NOT the standard for anything and should always be avoided in favor of using a flag since, as you've just discovered, it makes trivial jobs very slightly briefer but then anything even slightly more interesting requires a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions. Edit your question to show the desired output and we can hep you. I for one have absolutely no idea what it is you want to have output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to work as desired, but I can't help feel that it would be better to create a more easily parsed output format.

#### `script.awk`

```
/art/       { print; art++; next }
/subject/   { if (art < 3 && subject < 2) { print; subject++ } next }
            { if (art < 3 && subject < 2) print }
```

If the line contains `art`, print it and increment the 'art' count, and jump to the next line.  If the line contains 'subject' — then if the art count is less than 3 and the subject count is less than 2, print the line and increment the subject count, and jump to the next line.  Otherwise, if the art count is less than 3 and the subject count is less than 2, print the line.

#### Sample run

```
$ awk -f script.awk data
art
subject

Course Material
paint
brush
easel
beret

art

Skills learned
oil
pastel
ink
chalk


math
subject
$
```

This code is a little too well attuned to the sample data.
The 'art < 3' conditions should be 'art > 0 && art < 3'.  You also want to be able to choose the keywords.

```
BEGIN       { kw1 = "art"; kw2 = "subject" }
$1 ~ kw1    { print; nkw1++; next}
$1 ~ kw2    { if (nkw1 > 0 && nkw1 < 3 && nkw2 < 2) { print; nkw2++ } next }
            { if (nkw1 > 0 && nkw1 < 3 && nkw2 < 2) print }
```

And it would be nice to eliminate the `math` and `subject` lines at the end too.  For that, we need a more complex script that saves a line before printing it, remembering that the blank lines need printing too.

#### Revised `script.awk`

```
BEGIN       { kw1 = "art"; kw2 = "subject" }
$1 ~ kw1    { old = $0; nkw1++; next}
$1 ~ kw2    { if (nkw1 > 0 && nkw1 < 3 && nkw2 < 2)
              { if (nkw2 == 0) print old; old = $0; nkw2++ }
              next
            }
            { if (nkw1 > 0 && nkw1 < 3 && nkw2 < 2) { print old; old = $0 } }
```

#### Extended `data` file

```
english
subject

Course material
To Kill a Mockingbird
To Set a Watchman
Huckleberry Finn
Tom Sawyer

english

Skills learned
comprehension
dialectical analysis

art
subject

Course Material
paint
brush
easel
beret

art

Skills learned
oil
pastel
ink
chalk


math
subject

Course Material
book
calculator
etc...
```

#### Revised sample output

```
$ awk -f script.awk data
art
subject

Course Material
paint
brush
easel
beret
art

Skills learned
oil
pastel
ink
chalk


$
```

The revised script will only print out the first `art` block.  If there are other such blocks in the file, they are not printed (but no superfluous material is printed either).

You could arrange for the keywords to be passed to the script by revising the `BEGIN` block to check that `kw1` and `kw2` were set on the command line, for example, with:

```
awk -v kw1=art -v kw2=subject -f script.awk data
```

Comment: Awesome! I have been wrestling with this. I have to basically through 4,000 searches like this, each with its own unique "ART" (that is academic area of study) to the end "subject" that is the only constant I could use as an endpoint. I was had settled on using the NR as a way to give me a numerical range that could be manipulated easily.

Comment: I have gone through the O'Reilly books and a lot of resources on regex, awk, grep, etc. But they don't show you how to handle more complex regex searches or the syntax of how you program for awk. I started to use python to solve this because it is more transparent when I write it but awk is blindingly fast.  It's all of the details that I learned the hard way that keep me wary. What is awk's foundation for syntax, etc and what books or resources would you recommend? I like what it can do but am stymied by the lack of information to at least an intermediate++ level.

Comment: The O'Reilly book on `awk` and `sed` is pretty good.  I don't know if the book by AWK (Aho, Weinberger, Kernighan) is still available.  Otherwise, the GNU `gawk` manual is pretty good.

Comment: Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. All other awk books are out of date and/or otherwise incomplete. Awk is not hard to use but it requires a paradigm shift to learn how to use it correctly, just like going from procedural to object oriented programming. Once it clicks in your brain how much awk does for you internally and so how little code you need to write to do common text processing operations like reading a line and splitting it into fields, it's a breeze.

Comment: Thank you for all of y'alls help!

Answer (score 1):

This will start printing from the `art` and till the next to next `subject` is found:

```
awk '/^art/{f=1;j=1;} f{print} /subject/{if(j)i++; if(i%2==0){f=0;j=0;}}' filename    #j is used as a flag.
```

Output:

```
art
subject

Course Material
paint
brush
easel
beret

art

Skills learned
oil
pastel
ink
chalk


math
subject
```

If you don't want to print `math` and `subject`, @JonathanLeffler answer would be preferable.

Comment: Try your script on my 'Extended `data` file'.  It doesn't then produce the desired output.  Like my first script, yours is a little too finely attuned to the sample data.

Comment: More succinct than mine.  The "don't want subject" variant still prints the next block's heading line (the 'math' line, for example).  However, I'm sure you could eliminate that too with a bit of effort (maybe along the lines of the 'old' trick in my last script).

Comment: thank you again. I'm dissecting them to see how they work, and how to adapt them to a variety of situations.